# Blade returns undefined offset

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've started learning PHP Laravel and I'm struggling a bit with something (probably quite trivial). When I render my page I see the following error:

> ErrorException in BladeCompiler.php line 584: Undefined offset: 1

**Controller**

Located at \App\Http\Controllers\CompanyController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Company;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CompanyController extends Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $companies = Company::all();

        // return $companies;
        return view('public.company.index', compact('companies'));
    }

}
```

**View**

Located at \App\resources\views\public\company\index.blade.php

```
@extends('public.layout')

@section('content')
    Companies
    @foreach $companies as $company
        {{ $company->title }}
    @endforeach
@stop
```

When I uncomment `return $companies` in my Controller I do have result, but .. I'm not sure why my - very simple - view isn't rendering. Who can help me out?

Comment: Are you sure there is column title in your returned collection?

Comment: Yes, it was a silly syntax error. Thanks for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error point out that there was a issue while compiling blade file possibly because of syntax error.
So, just wrap the foreach variable inside paranthesis and the issue should be fixed.

```
@extends('public.layout')

@section('content')
    Companies
    @foreach ($companies as $company)
        {{ $company->title }}
    @endforeach
@stop
```

Comment: You totally made my day, thanks; I looked for over an hour to my code knowing it would be something trivial. I'm quite sure I won't forget this syntax anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check that `$companies` is set.

```
@extends('public.layout')

@section('content')
    @if(isset($companies))
        Companies
        @foreach $companies as $company
            {{ $company->title }}
        @endforeach
    @else
        {{-- No companies to display message --}}
    @endif
@stop
```

Comment: Why would you claim that? Compact is a pretty descent PHP function to pass data to laravel views.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'd like to keep my views clean and avoid unnecessary checks. It happens to be a syntax error. Thanks for looking into my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me crazy. The problem was that I included in **commented code** something like this:

```
// Never ever should you have a @ in comments such as @foreach 
// The reason is the blade parser will try and interpret the @directive
// resulting in a cryptic error: undefined index 1
```

I hope this helps someone. Spent too many hours commenting out all my @foreach **in code** only to find out that it was a directive **in comments** that was causing the issue in the first place.

Comment: That is a really stupid flaw in blade templates. Comments should not be parsed as logic.